# Using pthread in c++

Tags: c++, linker, pthreads, linker-errors

I am using `pthread.h` in a `*.cc` file. when I try to use `pthread_exit(0);` or `pthread_join(mythrds[yy],NULL);` it says:

```
.cc:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `pthread_exit'
```

when complied very similar code in a `*.c` file with  gcc it work perfect. How Can I use pthread's in c++.. (I also added -lpthread)

```
..
void *myThreads ( void *ptr )
{
...
pthread_exit(0); 
}
..
```

flags:

```
g++ -lpthread -Wall -static -W -O9 -funroll-all-loops -finline -ffast-math
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You might try using the -pthread option to g++.

```
   -pthread
       Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This
       option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.
```

Comment: thnks a lot, it reaaaaaaaallly helped. I thought -lpthread was doing the same think but it isnt.

Comment: You can find out what -pthread does on your platform using 'gcc -dumpspecs' and looking for things that begin '%{pthread'

Comment: The '-lpthread' option only includes the pthread library. That may not be sufficient on your platform to get pthreads support.

Answer (score 2):

Do your pthread header files have `extern "C" { ... }` around the function prototypes? That's the usual case for the linker not being able to link in C++.

It occurs because C++ generally does name-mangling so that it can encode parameter details into symbols (allowing polymorphism). For example, the functions:

```
void x(int);
void x(void);
void x(char,int,float,double);
```

all get different linker symbols.

If the header files *don't* have the `extern "C" { ... }`, you may need to do it yourself:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <pthread.h>
}
```

Hopefully that will work.

Comment: thnk but the problem was not that.