# g++ linking to external library creates undefined references

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I'm trying to build a simple program to test the use of an external library but am having trouble linking it with g++.  See command/results:

```
user@user-Nuvo-2510VTC:~/Desktop/WDT_DIO/linux/test$ g++ -o main main.o -lwdt_dio
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `sem_unlink'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `sem_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `pthread_spin_lock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `pthread_spin_unlock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `pthread_spin_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `pthread_spin_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `sem_post'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `sem_open'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `sem_getvalue'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libwdt_dio.so: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It looks like it isn't linking to some basic libraries that are part of the OS?

Details:

```
gcc --version --> 5.4.0 20160609
ldd --version --> 2.23
OS            --> Ubuntu 16.04 x64, 4.8.0-36-generic kernel
```

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [Using pthread in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2679885/608639) and [Compile/link error using pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6332410/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a link to the `pthread` library. Add `-pthread` to your compilation command:

```
g++ -o main main.o -pthread -lwdt_dio
```

Checking the man page for `sem_wait(3)` shows:

> Link with -pthread.

*Note: sem_wait was selected randomly, all of them should specify that*

Comment: Can't accept either yours or Petar's comments yet, but you were correct.  How'd you guys know what library was missing?  pthread was obvious but I didn't immediately recognize the semaphore functions were part of the same library

Comment: @NateGreco, I am familiar with these methods, but just in case I also added a straightforward explanation...

Comment: Perfect, thakns

Answer (score 1):

If you read the errors closely it says that the undefined comes from `libwdt_dio.so`. It also says to which function you have an undefined reference.

In this particular case, it is the pthread library. It should probably be mentioned as a dependency in WDT lib documentation.

You can add `-pthread` to your g++ command if you're compiling through the command line.