# undefined reference to pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, makefile, compilation

I want to compile a program which is using threads. I use the `#include <pthread.h>` library, however when I compile it using my make file I get the following errors:

```
file.c:(.text+0x378): undefined referece to `pthread_create`
file.c:(.text+0x3ad): undefined referece to `pthread_join`
```

The program run fine with the normal `gcc` compilator using `-lpthread` flag
The source of the make file that I am using:

```
CC=gcc
COMPILE.c=$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c
LINK.c=$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -lpthread


CFLAGS  = -Wall -O -I$(dir $(LIBLAB))

TEMPFILES = core core.* *.o temp.* *.out typescript*

all:
    @echo "Please compile directly the intended programs by name"

clean:
    rm -f ${TEMPFILES}
```

I have set the `-lpthread` flag in the make file but is not working, what changes should I make in the make file?

Comment: just use -pthread instead of -lpthread

Comment: @hetepeperfan tried that and I get the same error

Comment: What operating system?  What compiler?

Comment: You might have to do it at the CFLAGS variable I'm not sure. If i would compile it manually `gcc -pthread -o myprogram myprogram.c`

Comment: @AndrewHenle Linux mint

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679885/using-pthread-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @hetepeperfan yes, if I compile it the way you said it will compile but I have to compile it via that make file

Comment: You have to add `-pthread` in both the compile and link lines.  So add `CFLAGS = -pthread`.  You can remove `-lpthread` from the link line

Comment: @MadScientist same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replacement for `LINK.c` is wrong.  You can't add libraries to this because it means they appear on the link line first.

If you'd shown us the output of make, in addition to the makefile, probably we would have seen it more quickly.  Libraries like `-lpthread` must come at the *end* of the link line, after any objects that might have needed to use the library.

As I mentioned in comments, you should remove the `LINK.c` setting and add:

```
CFLAGS = -pthread
```

and that should be good enough.  If you do need to add libraries, you should use `LDLIBS` like this:

```
LDLIBS = -lpthread
```

not replace the `LINK.c` variable.